# Determine $\int^{\infty}_1 \frac1{x^2+x} \mathrm d x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Determine $$\int^{\infty}_1 \dfrac{1}{x^2+x} \mathrm d x$$

---

**My work**

We can use partial fraction decomposition to find that $\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)} = \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+1}$.

$\therefore \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \dfrac{1}{x^2+x} dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+1} dx$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty} (\ln(|x|) - 0) - \lim_{x \to 0} (\ln(|x + 1|) + \ln(2))$

---

My understanding is that, since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x|) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(|x + 1|) = \infty$, the integral should be divergent. However, the solutions suggest that the integral converges to $\ln(2)$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain where I am making an error.

Comment: Notice that $\ln|x|-\ln|x+1|=\ln|\frac x{x+1}|$,other than that it should be $\ln|x+1|-\ln 2$

Comment: Just because the integrals $\int_1^\infty \frac 1x dx$, $\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x+1}dx$ are divergent, doesn't mean that $\int_1^\infty (\frac 1x - \frac 1{x + 1})dx$ is divergent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it is easy to see that the integral must be convergent, since $1/x^2>1/(x^2+x)$ and $\int_1^{\infty} dx/x^2 = 1$. But one must be careful to only work with limits that exist: "$\infty-\infty$" is meaningless.

This is rather like the integral version of a telescoping series. Let's look at
$$ \int_1^{M} \frac{dx}{x^2+x} = \int_1^{M} \frac{dx}{x} - \int_1^{M} \frac{dx}{1+x}. $$
Changing variables in the second gives
$$ \int_1^{M} \frac{dx}{1+x} = \int_2^{M+1} \frac{dx}{x}, $$
so in fact,
$$ \int_1^{M} \frac{dx}{x^2+x} = \int_1^2 \frac{dx}{x} - \int_M^{M+1} \frac{dx}{x}. $$
The first of these is of course $\log{2}$. The second tends to zero, since the integral is bounded by the maximum of the function multiplied by the length of the interval of integration, so in particular it is bounded by $1/M \to 0$ as $M \to \infty$. Hence the integral converges to $\log{2}$ as $M \to \infty$.

---

The same obviously works for $f(x)-f(x+a)$ for any $f$ that converges to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_1^n\dfrac1{x^2+x}dx=\ln\left|\dfrac x{x+1}\right|_1^n=\ln\dfrac n{n+1}-\ln(2^{-1})$$

Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac n{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+\dfrac1n}=?$

Alternatively, $$\int_1^\infty\dfrac1{x^2+x}dx=\int_1^\infty\dfrac4{(2x+1)^2-1^2}dx$$

Set $2x+1=\sec u$

Answer (score 4):

Don't put $x$ as a limit of integration if $x$ is also the variable of integration.

Do this instead:

\begin{align*}
\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2 + x} &= \lim_{A \to +\infty} \int_1^A \frac{dx}{x^2+x}\\[0.3cm]
  &= \lim_{A \to +\infty}\left(\int_1^A \frac{dx}x - \int_1^A\frac{dx}{x+1}\right)\\[0.3cm]
  &= \lim_{A \to +\infty} \left(\ln|x|\bigg|_1^A - \ln|x+1|\bigg|_1^A\right)\\[0.3cm]
  &= \lim_{A\to+\infty} \left[\left(\ln |A| - \ln 1\right) - \left(\ln |A+1| - \ln 2\right)\right]\\[0.3cm]
  &= \lim_{A \to +\infty} \left(\ln| A| - \ln |A+1|\right) + \ln2\\[0.3cm]
  &= \lim_{A \to +\infty} \ln\left|\frac A{A+1}\right| + \ln2\\[0.3cm]
  &= \ln\left|\lim_{A \to +\infty} \frac A{A+1}\right| + \ln2\\[0.3cm]
  &= \ln 1 + \ln 2\\[0.3cm]
  &= \ln 2
\end{align*}

Comment: Having two separate limits of $A$ and $B$ is a little misleading.  The double limit $\lim_{A \to \infty} \lim_{B \to \infty} (A/B)$ could be equal to any number depending on the relationship between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Also, in your first step you write the convergent integral as a difference of two divergent integrals. That is a no-no.

Comment: CC @MichaelSeifert

Comment: Still not quite right; the second $\ln A$ should be $\ln(A+1)$, so then you need to be a bit more careful to show that those terms cancel in the limit.

Comment: Good lord.  No more Monday math for me.  Thanks @HansLundmark

Answer (score 3):

The mistake you are making is separating the terms of the integral. While it is true that the integrals of $x\mapsto{1\over x}$ and $x\mapsto{1\over x+1}$ are divergent on $[1, +\infty[$, their difference is not. As you noticed :

$${1\over{x(x+1)}} = {1\over x} - {1\over x+1}$$
of which a primitive is $x\mapsto \ln{x} - \ln{(x+1)}$ on $\Bbb R_+^*$, and this function has a limit at $+\infty$ (which is 0) so your integral converges.